# make Raspberry Pi 4 GPIO pins low while Startup and shutdown

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, bcm

I have used all 27 GPIO pins of raspberry pi for my hardware out of which few pins are active high at the startup as per Raspberry pi GPIO documentation.

I want to make GPIO0, GPIO6, GPIO7 and GPIO8 low while raspberry starts and shutdowns

I have tried to make GPIO low by adding some commands in config.txt.

```
gpio=0=op,dl
gpio=6=op,dl
gpio=7=op,dl
gpio=8=op,dl
```

but not working as expected

Comment: Make sure the I2C and SPI busses are deactivated.

Comment: @KlausD. i also want to use I2C and SPI in my program. Do i have to disable and enable both i2c and spi every time i start raspberry pi